# List access scopes from inside GCE VM instance

Tags: authorization, google-compute-engine

How can I find out from the command line of a Google Cloud Engine (GCE) VM instance which access scopes the instance possesses?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can retrieve it from the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata), run the command from within the VM instance:

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/?recursive=true" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

Scopes are in the serviceAccounts property of [instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/beta/instances).